# Fetch all Image names from blackberry Device

Tags: image, blackberry, java-me, photos

Is there any way to iterate through all images stored in a blackberry device. I have seen this [example](http://atif-razzaq.blogspot.com/2009/02/j2me-browsing-file-system-on-mobile.html) which iterates over the whole file system and scans each file. I am wondering is there any cheaper way of doing the same. Something that directly looks into the image directory?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `System.getProperty(String key)` it is possible to get image storage dirs on device:

1. Key "fileconn.dir.memorycard.photos". Returns default directory for storing photos on SD Card. It should be something like "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/".
2. Key "fileconn.dir.photos". Returns default directory for storing pictures on device memory. It should be something like "file:///store/home/user/pictures/".

Knowing these locations you can just iterage images inside of them, rather than scanning the whole file system. It is possible to list images using the [FileConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html) API. Specifically take a look at `list(String filter, boolean includeHidden)` method.