# How do I make a downloaded image show up in the Device's Gallery?

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, cordova

I have a phonegap photo-gallery application, with an option to download images to the device.

Currently, I'm able to save images into the SDCard of the device, but they don't show up in the Device's Photo-Library / Gallery application.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var remoteFile = encodeURI($("#imageView_content").find("img").attr("src"));
var localFileName = remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

var downloadSuccess = function() {
    alert("Download sucessful!\nFile Saved at: " + localFileName);
};
var handleDownloadedFile = function(entry) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, downloadSuccess, fail);
};
var startFileTransfer = function(fileEntry) {
    var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.download(remoteFile, localPath, handleDownloadedFile, fail);
};
var createLocalFile = function(dir) {
    dir.getFile(localFileName, {
        create : true,
        exclusive : false
    }, startFileTransfer, fail);
};
var createPhotosDir = function(fileSys) {
    fileSys.root.getDirectory("myAppName", {
        create : true,
        exclusive : false
    }, createLocalFile, fail);
};

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, createPhotosDir, fail);
```

I am using https://build.phonegap.com to build the app

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to use a path depending on the Device, but this doesn't seem to be working:

- On iOS (Simulator), the call fails - Path: `file:///private/var/root/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/myApp/`
- On Android, the download is successful,  but the images still don't show up on the Gallery until the device is restarted - Path: `dcim/myApp/`
- I couldn't test on BlackBerry, but I've set it up to try `file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/myApp/`, first and `file:///store/home/user/pictures/myApp/` on failure

Here's the Device detection code:

```
var platform = (device.platform || navigator.userAgent).toLowerCase();
if (platform.match(/iphone/i) || platform.match(/ipad/i) || platform.match(/ios/i)) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///private/var/root/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/", createPhotosDir_fromDir, callPhotosDir);
} else if (platform.match(/blackberry/i) || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/blackberry/i)) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/", createPhotosDir_BB, callPhotosDir);
} else if (platform.match(/android/i)) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, createPhotosDir_Droid, callPhotosDir);
} else {
    callPhotosDir();
}
```

And here are the directory selection functions:

```
var callPhotosDir = function() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, createPhotosDir, fail);
};
var createPhotosDir_fromDir = function(dir) {
    dir.getDirectory("myApp", {
        create : true,
        exclusive : false
    }, createLocalFile, callPhotosDir);
};
var createPhotosDir_Droid = function(fileSys) {
    fileSys.root.getDirectory("dcim/myApp", {
        create : true,
        exclusive : false
    }, createLocalFile, callPhotosDir);
};
var createPhotosDir_BB = function(dir) {
    dir.getDirectory("myApp", {
        create : true,
        exclusive : false
    }, createLocalFile, function() {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///store/home/user/pictures/", createPhotosDir_fromDir, callPhotosDir);
    });
};
```

Comment: what's your image's absolute path? if you save them as "image.jpg" instead of "image" they should appear on gallery.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, the downloaded image does have a valid extension, like `.jpeg` or `.jpg` or `.png`. The image's name is got through it's absolute URL in `localFileName` (see fist two lines of the code sample).

Comment: Then it should appear in your gallery unless you didn't set your file invisible. But as i see, you didn't. So try to restart your phone, because media browser needs to find them, but if you don't change anything in your directory that wouldn't be triggered.

Comment: On my Android, it shows up on my file explorer at `/sdcard/myAppName/image.jpg`, but doesn't show up on the Gallery, even after restarting the phone. Perhaps there is a particular path that the Gallery app scans for images on every Android?

Comment: Wait, It is showing up on my Android now, a while after restarting, so it looks like any path will do for Android :)

Comment: @yahya, do you happen to know of some way to force the Gallery to update without having to restart the phone?

Comment: @Sathvik unfortunately I do not, but you can refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html

Comment: I think mr. Sathvik, you should use sendBroadcast method to show up your image in gallery. But this method is only work for < 4.4.0

Answer (score 2):

Save them into the right place on the SDCard. BlackBerry devices mount the SDCard at /SDCard, so the full path would be `/SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/`

You can also create a subdirectory in the pictures directory, which will organize the photos when viewed from the photo gallery app.

Devices have built-in storage as well, though the capacity is substantially smaller than most SDCards. To save pictures there, use the path `/store/home/user/pictures/`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this path common across all BlackBerry devices? Do you happen to know of the path for Android and iOS?

Comment: For BlackBerry devices with a working SDCard inserted, this path should work.  SDCards are optional, so not all devices will have this.  iOS and Windows Phone don't have a general purpose filesystem exposed to third party apps, so the mechanisms are different there.  I'm not sure how Android works.

Comment: Well, thanks anyways @Micheal, Android seems to accept any path we give it. Any clue as to what path might work on BlackBerrys without an SDCard?

Comment: You will find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258612/fetch-all-image-names-from-blackberry-device

Comment: @EugenMartynov, thank you, those paths that Micheal mentioned, will work for BlackBerry, I'll also require paths for Android and iOS, do you happen to know of those?

Comment: @Sathvik maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154978/proper-way-to-save-pictures-inside-my-iphone-app and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DCIM

Answer (score 1):

When you close or stop your app,you should call this method.This is working for me for both 4.4 as well as lower android sdk version.

import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;

```
public void addImageIntoGallery() {
    String version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    if(! version.contains("4.4")){
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        String mCurrentPhotoPath = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myDirectory"; 
        File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }else{
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) 
              {
                  Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                  Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                  Log.i(TAG, "Scanned ................" + path);
              }
            });
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    addImageIntoGallery();
    super.onPause();
}
```